# unique count of the columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

i want to get a unique count of the of multiple columns containing the similar or different data...i am using sql server 2005...for one column i am able to take the unique count... but to take a count of multiple columns at a time, what's the query ?

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following selected, getting the data from a derived table:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct c1, c2, from t1) dt
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of combined unique column values, use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName GROUP BY UniqueColumn1, UniqueColumn2
```

To get the unique counts of multiple individual columns, use

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Column1), COUNT(DISTINCT Column2)
FROM TableName
```

Your question is not clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're getting at is individual SUMS from two unique columns in one query. I was able to accomplish this be using

```
SELECT FiscalYear, SUM(Col1) AS Col1Total, SUM(Col2) AS Col2Total
FROM TableName
GROUP BY FiscalYear
```

If your data is not numerical in nature, you can use CASE statements

```
SELECT FiscalYear, SUM(CASE WHEN ColA = 'abc' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ColATotal,
   SUM(CASE WHEN ColB = 'xyz' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ColBTotal
FROM TableName
GROUP BY FiscalYear
```

Hope this helps!